# nodejs npm install error, how to correct?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, nvm

I am trying to do npm install on a project that requires 'ref' and I get this error. Any idea how can I correct this?

I have nvm runnning and node -v = 0.10.26

ref@0.1.3 install /root/node-ffi-libvirt/nodejs-usage/ffi-libvirt/node_modules/ref

> node-gyp rebuild

```
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES, mkdir '/root/node-ffi-libvirt/nodejs-usage/ffi-libvirt/node_modules/ref/build'
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.11.0-12-generic
gyp ERR! command "nodejs" "/usr/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /root/node-ffi-libvirt/nodejs-usage/ffi-libvirt/node_modules/ref
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.15
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.10.9
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! ref@0.1.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ref@0.1.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the ref package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls ref
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.11.0-12-generic
npm ERR! command "node" "/root/.nvm/v0.10.26/bin/npm" "install" "ref"
npm ERR! cwd /root/node-ffi-libvirt/nodejs-usage/ffi-libvirt
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.4
```

Comment: Hi, did you solve it the issue? Maybe you can share the answer. I have a similar problem

Answer (score 1):

This suggests you don't have permission to create a directory.

It looks like the original project was installed as root (implied by the `/root` in the path) - so you must run the install as root as well.

Comment: that does not make much sense unfortunately :/ and npm install should never be run as sudo as per the recommended approach.

Comment: recommended or not, the fact remains the error appears to be a permissions issue.

Answer (score 0):

try mkdir '/root/node-ffi-libvirt/nodejs-usage/ffi-libvirt/node_modules/ref/build' with the user you are running the command from. Fix that first and then run your command.

Comment: tried doing that. did a mkdir and ran a npm install, but, looks like it deletes the dir and tries to mkdir it again.

Comment: Ofcourse. I did not pay attention to the directory I was asking you to recreate. Better to not have node_modules in this directory at all. Set NODE_PATH env variable to a safe directory and use that to contain your node_modules.